# XMLHttpRequest allows one URL but throws NetworkError on another

Tags: javascript, google-api, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm using the Google Maps APIs for a web application I'm writing, and now I'm running into cross-domain request issues. What's strange is that `XMLHttpRequest.send()` succeeds when using `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=..."` but fails with a `NetworkError` when doing a GET request to `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=...&destination=..."`.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
// HTTP GET request
function httpGetJSON(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, false);
    req.send(null);
    return JSON.parse(req.responseText);
}

// lat/lon of street address
function locationOfAddress(address) {
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
        encodeURIComponent(address);
    var response = httpGetJSON(url);
    return response.results[0].geometry.location;
}

// driving distance between street addresses
function drivingDistance(addressFrom, addressTo) {
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +
        encodeURIComponent(addressFrom) + "&destination=" + 
        encodeURIComponent(addressTo);
    var response = httpGetJSON(url);
    return response.routes[0].legs[0].distance;
}

// getting lat/lon of White House works
var center = locationOfAddress("1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500");
// getting distance from White House to Capitol Building fails with NetworkError
var dist = drivingDistance(
    "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500",
    "2 15th St NW, Washington, DC 20007");
```

The only difference between the two URLs is that one is accessing the `geocode` API while the other uses the `directions` API, and of course that the query strings are different.

Why would these differences make one `HTTP GET` request succeed and the other fail?

(Note: I've checked both URLs and both get JSON responses when put into any web browser)

Comment: url encode the strings before concatenation

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera nope, didn't work :(

Comment: are you sure see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera yes, I am sure; I encoded the URL exactly how the link you posted suggested.

Comment: have you tried a different destination? one without `&`

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera yes I have; it didn't work. I'll edit the question to make things more clear.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730930/ajax-returns-error-when-calling-google-api